# Shell script password with special chars

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, password, mysql

I've build a shell mysql backup script which works very well.

It only has problems with passwords with special chars like this:
`xgT{uic[Is?uJ+`.

Here is the important part of the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
FILE=mysql-$db.$DATE.sql.gz
ssh $SUSER@$SHOST "mysqldump -q -u $MUSER -h $MHOST -p$MPASS $db --no-create-db | gzip -9 > $FILE" 2> $ERROR
```

I've changed it to:

```
ssh $SUSER@$SHOST 'mysqldump -q -u $MUSER -h $MHOST -p'\''$MPASS'\'' $db --no-create-db | gzip -9 > $FILE' 2> $ERROR
```

As you can see I've already tried double quotes. But now I get the error:

> ```
> bash: $FILE: ambiguous redirect
> ```

I'm getting the password and other info from an external file:

```
DB_HOST=000.000.000.000
DB_DATABASE=dbdame
DB_USER=db user
DB_PASS="xgT{uic[Is?uJ+"
```

Within my script it take the info from the external file:

```
Source dbserver.conf
MUSER=$DB_USER
MPASS=$DB_PASS
MHOST=$DB_HOST
DBS=$DB_DATABASE
```

Comment: I was able to have it echo your special character string without a problem.  What was your error before you quoted the password?

Comment: It was: "mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user '...'@'...' (using password: YES) when trying to connect

Comment: That's exactly the error '...'@'...' or did you mask that? Obviously keep your username and password secret, but did it omit some characters, or the entire string?

Comment: I've masked it. The original error was with the correct user and address.

Comment: Could be the problem that I'm getting the password from an external file?:

Comment: If it is mysql, consider using a `~/.my.cnf` file in the server: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16299603/mysql-utilities-my-cnf-option-file

Comment: That could be a way. But I prefer having all configuration data on my backup target server. So what do I have to change to to be able to transfer the correct password?

Answer (score 1):

Your password needs to have the special characters escaped. So if your original password is `xgT{uic[Is?uJ+`it will have to become `xgT\{uic\[Is\?uJ\+` (A slash before the special characters).

You might also want to look at something already written to do this such as [AutoMySQLBackup](https://sourceforge.net/projects/automysqlbackup/), but I'm not sure if you need daily, weekly or monthly backup rotations. However the same rule applies, if the password has special characters those special characters need to be escaped.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It helped to escape special chars:

```
MPASS=$(printf "%q\n" "$DB_PASS")
```

But there was still a problem with mysqldump. I finally found out, that mysqldump only worked for me with passwords with special characters when I don't tell mysqldump the host (-h hostname). This seems to be a bug. Or isn't it?

Unfortunately I also have sites where the mysql server is an other host. So this solution isn't perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You should write like this:

```
ssh "$SUSER@$SHOST" "mysqldump -q -u \"$MUSER\" -h \"$MHOST\" -p\"$MPASS\" \"$db\" --no-create-db | gzip -9 > \"$FILE\"" 2> "$ERROR"
```

That is, all variables used as command line arguments should be protected by enclosing within quotes. The double-quotes around variables ensure that the expression is treated as a single value, so the shell will not split it to words. Notice that `"` embedded within `"..."` need to be escaped,
and written as `\"`. A simpler solution is to use single-quotes instead of the embedded double-quotes, like this:

```
ssh "$SUSER@$SHOST" "mysqldump -q -u '$MUSER' -h '$MHOST' -p'$MPASS' '$db' --no-create-db | gzip -9 > '$FILE'" 2> "$ERROR"
```

Lastly, I'm wondering if you really meant to have `2> "$ERROR"` on the local host, and not on the remote host. I suspect you actually wanted that on the remote host, so that's another error in the original command line.
If that's the case, then here's the fix:

```
ssh "$SUSER@$SHOST" "mysqldump -q -u '$MUSER' -h '$MHOST' -p'$MPASS' '$db' --no-create-db | gzip -9 > '$FILE' 2> '$ERROR'"
```